# left shifting a positive int is giving me a negative number

Tags: c

I´m using shift to make optimizations on some math I have to do in a program written in C:

```
int h;
h = 104;
h = (h<<8)+(h<<6);
printf("offset: %d",h);
```

I get this result:

```
offset: -32256
```

When what I expect is

```
(104* (2^8) ) +  (104 * (2^6)) = 33280
```

Can anyone explain why I´m getting the negative result and what can I do to get the result I expect?

I´m using the BORLANDC compiler with DOSBOX to run my program if that´s useful.

Comment: If ints are only 16 bits in that environment, you're well into "setting the sign bit" territory with those shifts (33280 definitely has the sign bit of a 16 bit int set)

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Just edited my comment - expected result = 0x8200, so clearly the addition of the 2 shifts does cause the a 16 bit overflow issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems In the environment where the program was run type `int` has width of 2 bytes and its maximum value is `+32767`.

So when a positive value exceedes this limit then the sign bit can be set and you get a negative value.

You can check the maximum poisitive value that can be stored in an object of type int the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main( void )
{
    printf( "The maximum is %d\n", INT_MAX );
}
```

Instead of the type int you could use type `unsigned int` or type `long` or `unsigned long`

For example the maximum value for type `unsigned int` provided by your compiler can be equal to `65535`. It is enough to store the result of your expression.

Answer (score 5):

On Borland C compiler, the size of int is 16-bits. So the statement

```
h = (h<<8)+(h<<6);
```

[overflows a signed integer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow). The individual shift operations are fine as the results are within the limit of what a 16-bit signed integer can hold. But the addition results in overflow. Signed integer overflow is [*undefined behaviour*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in C.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Is there any way I can make this a number positive. Can I explictly change the size of an int in the BORLAND compiler?

Comment: You can change the type of `h` to `unsigned int`. But that gives twice the range which is also very small on a 16-bit machine (2^16 - 1). So you need to be care if you are going to use signed ints. Unsigned integers don't overflow but wrap around. So the behaviour is defined but still may not very useful if you want to do calculations.